# Chart data labels: Skip blank rows using value from cells

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Is it possible to instruct the "value from cells" label option to skip blank rows (preferably without vba)?

I've added data labels for numerical data as well as adjacent grading values which I've designated via the value from cells option. Unfortunately, the value from cells portion returns a blank instead of a letter grade every time it encounters a blank row (the pivot table header row). This then shifts the alignment all my grades, and gets worse if I do any sort of filtering on the table/chart.

[image: img1]

Comment: Does [this link from the Microsoft documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/884406/a-line-chart-may-plot-gaps-in-lines-when-the-data-range-contains-blank) help?

Comment: Unfortunately not, using the Excel 2007 instructions, the "Connect data points with line" is greyed out. I can't go the formula route because the pivot table won't let me add values to a cell like that.